# Android Koltin Room Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am newbie as android developer and i try to use kotlin room database. i made a shopping app and i have a problem. i use table like i post[Table that i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OVEX.png). i tried embed table_2 to table_1 with left join, but as you can see in table_2, there are same rows with different barcode number. i tried to choose one them but i failed. Every time i did, product_id in one row has many barcode. So i need advice. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: please use a more descriptive title

Answer (score 0):

Have a POJO (not an entity which is a table) you embed table_1 (the parent) with the [@Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded) annotation and relate to a list of table_2 (the children) using the [@Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation) annotation.

e.g.

```
data class Table_1WithTable_2List(
    @Embedded
    val table_1: Table_1,
    @Relation(
        entity = Table_2::class,
        parentColumn = "productId",
        entityColumn = "productId"
    )
    val table_2List: List<Table_2>
)
```

and then use a Dao such as :-

**Correction** :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_1")
fun getAllTable_1sWithAListOfTheTable_2Children(): List<Table_1WithTable_2List>
```

**Working Example**

Consider that table_1 is populated with :-

[image]

and table_2 with :-

[image]

Then :-

```
    for(t1t2: Table_1WithTable_2List in dao.getAllTable_1sWithAListOfTheTable_2Children()) {
        Log.d("TABLE_1INFO","Product is ${t1t2.table_1.productName} it has ${t1t2.table_2List.size} Table2s. They are:-")
        for (t2: Table_2 in t1t2.table_2List) {
            Log.d("TABLE_2INFO","\tBarcode is ${t2.productBarcode}")
        }
    }
```

results in the log showing :-

```
D/TABLE_1INFO: Product is Product1 it has 2 Table2s. They are:-
D/TABLE_2INFO:  Barcode is BarcodeA
D/TABLE_2INFO:  Barcode is BarcodeX
D/TABLE_1INFO: Product is Product2 it has 1 Table2s. They are:-
D/TABLE_2INFO:  Barcode is BarcodeY
D/TABLE_1INFO: Product is Product3 it has 3 Table2s. They are:-
D/TABLE_2INFO:  Barcode is BarcodeZ
D/TABLE_2INFO:  Barcode is BarcodeZZ
D/TABLE_2INFO:  Barcode is BarcodeZZZ
D/TABLE_1INFO: Product is product4 it has 0 Table2s. They are:-
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i' ll try it.

Comment: @mboluk oops messed up with the Dao just about to edit the answer.

Comment: @mboluk corrected.

Comment: Is there other way that i do not create dao? I actually have dao and when i create a new function, all other function have to be changed. So I want to change query. Is there any way like filtering?

Comment: @mboluk An interface (or abstract class) annotated with `@Dao` can have multiple functions (Dao's), you can also have multiple interfaces/abstract class annotated with `@Dao` just have multiple abstract functions to get the Dao in the class annotated with `@Database`. Filtering on Table_1 is simple just alter the SQL accordingly. Filtering Table_2 using `@Relation` will not work as Room build the underlying SQL to get ALL of the related Table_2's (can be done BUT definitely another question)